# Does anyone know the Watcom .lib file for SOCKET.H?

Tags: c, sockets, linker-errors, dos, watcom

I have been trying to make a dos communication program. Upon finding the header files I would need, I realized that when I tried to link

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define FD_SETSIZE          1024
#define __NFDBITS           (8 * sizeof (fd_mask))
#define __FDELT(d)          ((d) / __NFDBITS)
#define __FDMASK(d)         ((fd_mask) 1 << ((d) % __NFDBITS))
#define __FDS_BITS(set) ((set)->fds_bits)
typedef long fd_mask;

typedef struct {
    fd_mask fds_bits[FD_SETSIZE / __NFDBITS];
} fd_set;

#include<sys/socket.h> 

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int socket_desc;
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

When I link this code, I get an error that `socket()` is not defined.

Does anyone have any ideas to what the solution to this could be?
Does anyone have any ideas of which library file implements the 'sock' function?

Comment: @Ryanwuzhere None of them. TCP/IP was a third-party product on MS.DOS. Microsoft didn't believe in TCP/IP until about 1995, hence this fiasco and the subseqeuent Winsock fiasco. And Watcom didn't provide it. You will need to source a third-party product.

Comment: NB When you *link* this code you get an error that *`socket()`* is not defined.